# CEF don't load pages from URL

Tags: url, chromium-embedded

I've succeeded integrating CEF with my wxWidgets application, but It don't render pages when using `CefFrame::LoadURL` it only loads and renders content successfully if the `CefFrame::LoadString` function is called.

If the requested URL is not valid or not found it outputs an in-browser error with `code=-106`

The code calling the CEF:

```
    CefMainArgs main_args(wxGetApp().argc, wxGetApp().argv);        
    SampleCefApp *sampleAppObj = new SampleCefApp(frame);
    CefRefPtr<SampleCefApp> app(sampleAppObj);

    int exit_code = CefExecuteProcess(main_args, app.get(), NULL);
    if (exit_code >= 0)
    {
        return exit_code;
    }

    CefSettings settings;

    CefString(&settings.javascript_flags).FromASCII("--harmony");

    // Initialize CEF for the browser process.
    CefInitialize(main_args, settings, app.get(), NULL);

    CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> cefBrowserObj = sampleAppObj->theBrowser;
    CefRefPtr<CefFrame>   cefMainFrame  = cefBrowserObj->GetMainFrame();
    cefMainFrame->LoadURL("file://home/sameh/Code/wxCEF/resources/app.html");
```

---

Output application screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code -106 from net_error_list.h (http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/net/base/net_error_list.h):

```
// The Internet connection has been lost.
NET_ERROR(INTERNET_DISCONNECTED, -106)
```

Try loading the url by pasing it to the CreateBrowser() function and see if that helps. It might be a timing issue, CreateBrowser() works asynchronously, browser/frame may not yet be ready for use when calling LoadURL(). Try using CreateBrowserSync() instead.

EDIT.
There should be three slashes after the file protocol, `file://home/czarek/asd.txt` generates error in Google Chrome, while `file:///home/czarek/asd.txt` works fine.

Comment: I've created the browser with *CreateBrowserSync()* and it don't work even if I pass the url to the function:
---

`theBrowser = CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowserSync(window_info, handler.get(), url, browser_settings, NULL);`

Comment: Also I've tired local files, it don't render if the file exists and otherwise it omits error with `code=-105`

Comment: `LoadURL` from offline file has worked when I added the extra *\*, but I still can figure out how to render online website from its url, what I path as url is `"url=http://www.google.com"`

Comment: @SamehKamal 1. What is the error code? 2. Does it reproduce with the cefclient sample application? 3. What settings are you using, are you passing any proxy settings? 4. Does the problem also occur in Google Chrome? 5. Do you have custom proxy settings in Internet Explorer options?

Comment: There no errors it only show a white page and don't draw the html content. and if I click view source, it appears as empty